# How to get the Daily Income data of masternode

Tags: bitcoin, roi, ico, reward-system

I am going to calculate the daily income of masternode, but I am a new in this field so I don`t know how to get the data from which.
I am going to obtain them using transaction history(They are provided from API),
but I am not sure I am correct or not.
[image]